# Framework em C# que implementa a Teoria de Grafos

Tags: c#, grafo

Alguém conhece algum framework em C# e que implemente a Teoria dos Grafos?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Conheço duas bibliotecas que podem ser usadas juntas:

- [Graph#](http://graphsharp.codeplex.com/)
- [QuickGraph](http://quickgraph.codeplex.com/) - [Tem pacote NuGet](https://www.nuget.org/packages/QuickGraph/)

Graph# é uma biblioteca gráfica para WPF. QuickGraph é uma biblioteca para grafos genéricos.

Há ainda o [Microsoft Automatic Graph Layout](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/projects/msagl/).

Comment: Obrigado! Pesquisando na net não achei muitas opções tb.. só essas duas... só achei pobre a documentação do QuickGraph ;(

Comment: @JuniorGasparotto Projetos pequenos não possuem muita documentação. O jeito é usar exemplos da Internet.